# Inner measure does not agree with outer measure until measurability holds

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ with $m^*(A)<\infty$ by definition of outer measure $m^*$,
I can show that $$m^*(A)=\inf\{m^*(O)\ : \ O \text{ is an open set containing }A\}$$ due to the fact that for all $\epsilon>0, \exists$ open set $O$ containing $A$ such that $m^*(O)-m^*(A)<\epsilon$.

But, intuitively, $m^*(A)=\sup\{m^*(F):F \text{ is an closed set contained in } A\}$ should not hold in general until the set is measurable, since $m^*$ is merely outer measure. But, since I am new to measure theory, I have not find a counter example for this. Any suggestion of the counter example will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right, this is hard to see in a decisive way. The conceptually most convincing proof that not every subset of the real line can be Lebesgue measurable (that is, even after "completing", or in whatever logical order one does things...) uses the Axiom of Choice. Indeed, I believe in some models of smaller fragments of set theory with variant axioms (like Godel's "V=L"?) with fewer subsets of the reals, all subsets _are_ measurable.

Comment: Although @paulgarrett is right that non-measurable sets can't be really explicit, since their existence depends on the axiom of choice (AC), the use  of AC here is not terribly complicated. Look up "Vitali set".

Comment: @paulgarrett Gödel's V=L implies AC. In fct that's how Gödel proved that AC is consistent relative to ZF.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, oop, yes, of course. Unfortunately I apparently do not remember the set-theoretic situation in which all subsets of the reals are measurable... Surely someone here does?

Comment: @paulgarrett Solovay built a model of ZF in which all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable. He begins with a model of ZFC in which there is an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, then he uses forcing to enlarge the model by adding bijections between $\mathbb N$ and each cardinal $<\kappa$, and finally he passes to the submodel of sets hereditarily ordinal-definable from reals.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, ah, good. Also, then, by this year do we know consistency of existence of inaccessibles with ZFC? In my youth, I think these were not known ... ?

Comment: @paulgarrett On the one hand, ZFC can't prove the existence of inaccessibles (unless ZFC is inconsistent and thus proves everything), nor can ZFC prove "if ZFC is consistent then so is (ZFC + there is an inaccessible)" (unless ZFC proves its own inconsistency). On the other hand, like many set-theorists, I know that the existence of inaccessibles is consistent with ZFC. I know this on the basis of my intuitive understanding of the standard universe of sets (the same way I know lots of other mathematics is consistent).

Comment: @AndreasBlass, thanks for the info!